# how can I dismiss keyboard when I will just touch anywhere except UITextField?

Tags: iphone, keyboard, uitextfield, numeric-keypad

Hello
I have two UITextFields in my application, and want to dismiss the keyboard when I just touch anywhere except the UITextFields
how can I do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use tochesBegin method for this purpose

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  [yourFirstTextField resignFirstResponder];
  [yourSecondTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

You do not need any thing else.When you touch anywhere on view then both textField resign no need to to know which one having focus.and when you touch textField then textField open keyboard by own.

Comment: Ji, It is working perfectly, I have accepted your answer, Thanx :-)

Comment: I also added "[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];" just in case.

Answer (score 11):

The answer by [Ishu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941332/how-can-i-dismiss-keyboard-when-i-will-just-touch-anywhere-except-uitextfield/4941394#4941394) is a good one. But I think you should also give a try to :

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

  [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I dunno why but resignFirstResponder weren't working for me. This works a treat.

Comment: @Deco have you linked your responder with the correct IBOutlet in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom button at the background and then connect it to the `IBAction` method that calls `resignFirstResponder` on the your `UITextField`

something like this
[image]

Edit:

as you want to add the button programmatically than you can use this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    button.buttonType = UIButtonTypeCustom;
    [button addTarget:self action:(buttonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:button];
    [button release];
```

and than add your controller code after this.

Comment: my all Coding is manual, not Interface Builder based, so how can I call a method simply, can U tell me?

Comment: add a tap gesture instead

Answer (score 1):

Create an invisible button, put it behind the `UITextField` and send `resignFirstResponder` message to your text fields when the button is tapped.

Comment: And make the transparent button cover the entire view, so that any touch other than the text field on top of it will activate the button.

Answer (score 1):

Use delegate,

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
 [textField resignFirstResponder];
 return YES;
}
```

You can also create a method in your controller

```
 -(IBAction)editingEnded:(id)sender{
    [sender resignFirstResponder]; 
}
```

and then in Connection Inspector in IB connect Event "Did End On Exit" to it.

Comment: I am creating a method like this, but now how to call it when anywhere clicked except my textFields                                                                                                 - (void) backgroundTap {
 [self.restaurant_name_textfield resignFirstResponder];
 [self.amount_textfield resignFirstResponder];
}

Comment: my all Coding is manual, not Interface Builder based, so how can I call a method simply, can U tell me?

Answer (score 1):

Typically in this scenario you will have a scroll view holding the rest of the User Interface.  If you assign the delegate of that scroll view to your view controller, and say that you implement the protocol `UIScrollViewDelegate`, then just adding the following method will do the job:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using Interface builder, you can manually hook up events as explained here:
[How can I programmatically link an UIView or UIImageView with an event like "touch up inside"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910334/how-can-i-programmatically-link-an-uiview-or-uiimageview-with-an-event-like-touc)

If you are using Interface builder, then you don't need to create a background button.

You could do this:

1. Select your view (probably called View)
2. Change to the (i) tab in the property inspector
3. Change the class from UIView to UIControl (this gives you access to the *Touch Down* event).
4. Hook the *Touch Down* event to your backgroundTap method (Ctrl + drag).
5. Don't forget to Save changes

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to define the action for your button click this way

[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


And implement the click method ,as for example i have provided the animation on button click method.
-(void)backButtonClicked
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animation" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO]; 
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}


Hope this will help you ,the action is without using IB.Its all done through coding
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{

    const int movementDistance = 180; distace of keyboard up.

    const float movementDuration = 0.3f;

     int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];

    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Keep a reference to the UITextField in your view controller and call [yourTextField resignFirstResponder]

Comment: what does you mean reference, how can I code it, please explain a bit more

Comment: I mean just have an IBOutlet to the UITextField, then when there is a touch even anywhere else, call [yourTextField resignFirstResponder]