# Hide keyboard on touch anywhere outside UITextField when view includes UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, first-responder

There are some answers out there such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4941332/how-can-i-dismiss-keyboard-when-i-will-just-touch-anywhere-except-uitextfield), but in the case where there is a `UIScrollView` or `UICollectionView` present, it doesn't work.
The `touchesBegan` method on the `viewController` will never get called.

On screen, I have a `UITextField` at the top.
Below that, filling up the rest of the screen is a `UICollectionView`.
I need to dismiss the keyboard if I touch anywhere besides the `UITextField` (*including the collection view obviously*)

So what is the best way to do this?

For such a common UI paradigm it seems like there should be a well-known solution, but I've yet to come across it.

Comment: have you tried [TPKeyboardAvoiding](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding)?

Answer (score 4):

To dismiss Keyboard on tap of the View: Add a Tap gesture to your ViewController.collectionView as follows:

```
//declare a property to store your current responder
@property (nonatomic, assign) id currentResponder;
//in viewDidLoad:

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resignOnTap:)];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [singleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];


//Implement the below delegate method:

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    self.currentResponder = textField;
}

//Implement resignOnTap:

- (void)resignOnTap:(id)sender {
    [self.currentResponder resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: This would work if the user taps the collection view, but I wish there was a more general solution for any touch outside the keyboard.

Comment: I don't think there is any other easy way around. any how you have to implement gesture recognition here. Let me know if my answer is useful ..:)

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do it is:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.view endEditing:YES]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better solution which doesn't require adding gesture recognisers individually to everything. It's in Swift, but could easily be converted to ObjC.

Add the following to your viewDidLoad():

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

and then add the following method declaration:

```
func dismissKeyboard()
{
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

...where `view` is your text field.